# How to create a Connector using REST URL having headers?

Tags: mcs

I have a REST URL that has header parameters.How can I create a REST connector using that REST URL in oracle MCS.

The REST URL is POST method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably this is the same question asked and answered on the OTN Forums: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4023706

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your question on OTN forum . 
Please add the endpoint specified on the "Rules" section of Connector creation while testing .(as per your screen shot uploaded on OTN forum)